# Get date from cell and place in another cell formatted

Tags: excel

I have a date field in cell **N13** in the format "`mm/dd/yyyy`". and I am trying to concatenate this date as a file name in cell **A1**. To simplify, let's just put the the date in the following format in cell **A1** "`mm-dd-yyyy`".

I have tried the following formula but get a **#NAME?** error: `=Format(N13, "mm-dd-yyyy")`

Comment: When you begin typing `=Format` in to the cell, you should observe that it does not appear in the list of available functions. That's what the `#Name` error means here.  `Format` is a VBA function.

Comment: Yes, you are correct David. I am more of a VBA programmer and it go the best of me, hehehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(N13,"mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: Hey, it worked and much simpler than my answer. I had already tried mine before I tested your answer. They want to delete this post anyways because it is apparently off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I was mixing VBA with Excel functions, so I came up with the following

```
=IF(MONTH(N13)<10,0&MONTH(N13),MONTH(N13)) & "-" & IF(DAY(N13) < 10,0 & DAY(N13),DAY(N13)) & "-" & YEAR(N13)
```